# When using a for loop to add objects to an array, the last object that is added is used for all instances

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

Ive been trying to use a for loop to add instances of a driver to a driver array. Each driver has 3 basic variables that are gathered through the for loop. When the loop runs though, the details of the last driver are stored in all of the indexes of the array! I want to get it so that i can add each individual driver to the array.

```
public static void addDriver(Driver[] d) {      //method using for loop to add drivers


    for(int i = 0; i < d.length; i++ ) {


        String name, DOB, occupation;

        System.out.println("Please Enter Driver Name");
        name = kb.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Please Select Driver Occupation");
        System.out.println("1: Chauffeur" + "\n2: Accountant");
        int choice = kb.nextInt();
        kb.nextLine();

        if (choice == 1) {
            occupation = "Chauffeur";
        } else {
            occupation = "Accountant";
        }

        System.out.println("Please Enter Driver D.O.B");
        DOB = kb.nextLine();

        d[i]  = new Driver(name, occupation, DOB);

    }
}
```

any and all help greatly appreciated!

edit...

here is the code from the main method, i get the size of the array from a separate method called driverNum.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int drivers = driverNum();      //Setting size of the array

    Driver[] d = new Driver[drivers];       //creating new array using number of drivers to be insured

    addDriver(d);       //calling method to add drivers to array

    for(int x = 0; x < d.length; x++)
    {
        System.out.println(d[x].toString());
    }

}
```

here is the Driver class that i have been using...

```
public class Driver {

static String name, occupation, DOB;

public Driver()
{
    name = "";
    occupation = "";
    DOB = "";
}

public Driver(String name, String occupation, String DOB)
{
    this.name = name;
    this.occupation = occupation;
    this.DOB = DOB;
}

public void setName(String name)
{
    this.name = name;
}

public String getName(Driver d)
{
    return name;
}

public void setOccupation(String occupation)
{
    this.occupation = occupation;
}

public String getOccupation()
{
    return occupation;
}

public void setDOB(String DOB)
{
    this.DOB = DOB;
}

public String getDOB()
{
    return DOB;
}

public String toString()
{
    String s;

    s = "Name: " + name;
    s = s + "\nOccupation: " + occupation;
    s = s + "\nDOB: " + DOB;

    return s;
}
}
```

Ive been scratching my head over this for a while now, because i thought it was correct. Thanks for the help so far!

Comment: What is the value of `d.length` before your loop?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, this seems like it should work. Can you post the code where you are calling this method and printing out the results of it?

Comment: I don't think there are any mistakes here. As @JamalH said, post the code where you are calling this method, that might help.

Comment: Also add the `Driver` class definition please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Driver` class, you defined your three global variables, `name`, `occupation`, and `D.O.B` as `static`. This means that whenever you change the value of that variable, it will change *everywhere* in the program, even if you create multiple instances of that class. Just take out the static declaration and that should solve your problem.